# Specific form of pull up technique question

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, pull-ups, calisthenics

I'm on progression of doing a muscle up and currently on the level of doing the following pull up exercise https://youtu.be/q1iSDKwTuiY?t=173 but I can't wrap my head around it, in the video it's called `strict lat pulldown` and in other source that I'm learning through it's called `pull out`, but I can't find more anywhere on the internet about it. Can someone please give me some advice on how to do it or point to a video with explanation, how it's really called etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muscle ups are easier to get by doing [kip to supports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Up7ZXvjkY0s) for high volume, as you get stronger decrease the kick and increase the pull. If you can do at least 1 pull up you can do a lot of kipping muscle ups. 
[image]

> Can someone please give me some advice on how to do it or point to a video with explanation, how it's really called etc. ?

The name doesn't matter, call it partial muscle up, swinging pullover or however you like it, it's just the beginning motion of a kipping muscle up.

You see the guy literally jumping on the bar to get momentum and then doing a pendulum motion. Imagine the outer position of a headbanger pull up but with vertical momentum.

Comment: I don't have the rings though... But I'll try more, thanks I guess.